# Why URL's "path" such as index.html was hidden?

Tags: web, url

In modern Website usually hidden path.

use this

```
https://google.com/main
```

instance of this

```
https://google.com/main.html
```

but I want to ask why they chose to hidden the file path.
I know that Initial web was use this file path.
But if they chose to cover up it, I think there was some reason.

Because of they just think it doesn't look good?
Or is there a security issue when using a file root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in tranditional website.all content on the page is static and write in html file.so we can fetch and show the page directly by browser.
in modern internet,the content we browse is dynamic,for example we browse a news page,the content changed every second,so the server handle our request by some function not handle by a static html file,the function always print out latest news,so it is dynamic,not a unchanged static html file.